# Saving a constantly updating array of data with merging into MySQL (possible concurrency issue)

Tags: php, mysql, updates

Currently we have a PHP base, and within that, users can login to their accounts.  Our site is pretty big and our developers want a way to store an arbitrary amount of data to benefit each user (so it may be something they entered onto a page and we can load the page with differing values based on the fact they did that when they go back).

The problem is that I am not sure of the best way to store this persistent data.  My initial thought was to store it in a serialized PHP array in the MySQL database.  This works just fine except that we run into a concurrency problem where the user opens one page, which pulls the array, decides it needs to be modified, and does so, and in the meantime, they have a page open in another tab which has pulled the same original copy of the array, decides it needs a different modification, and writes that to the database, so only one page "wins" and a change is lost.  It is quite likely (and currently does happen), that users open multiple pages of our site in differing tabs so we do need to account for this.

The second solution was just an extension on the first one, where we could store a timestamp in MySQL of the update time, and if the entire array had been updated since the developer pulled it, they would need to re-pull the entire array, check their changes are still relevant and re-submit it so it would then become the new array.  This seems kind of messy but it's the best solution I have at the moment, does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Can you just use extra columns in the user table? If there are a lot, and some users may not have any, you could have a user profile table that has a 1:1 relationship with the user table. Lastly, a key-value string pairs table has worked well for me in the past. The serialisation idea does work in certain cases, but of course it completely hides the data from database-level searching, sorting and joining, so should be avoided if you can.

Comment: @halfer, the key-value design (also called Entity-Attribute-Value) doesn't fix the concurrency issue, and it introduces a lot of other problems.

Comment: @Bill: it depends on what concurrency issues the OP is referring to, I think. I assumed that, since his array of values is presently serialised, writing "one" value in such a design in fact writes them all, and spoils other values that have been added, deleted or updated in the meantime. I agree key-value designs are not always optimal, but adding/updating/deleting key "name" for user 1234 should be atomic.

Comment: @halfer, unless someone else has been editing the *same* key in another session. Any `UPDATE` is atomic, but the cycle is really `SELECT ` to read the current value, present it to the user, let them edit it and then post it back using `UPDATE`.

Comment: @Bill, true. Peter, to fix _that_ problem (and regardless of how you end up storing your data) your form could contain a last_updated hidden field, and then upon saving if this does not agree with the database copy, reject the edit and ask the user to refresh.

Comment: The problem is ultimately both issues, with @BillKarwin describing the issue best.  In my above described situation, it's really just a key-value store but the user ID is the key and the serialized data is the value.  The concurrency issue is any case in which the same key is being edited at the same time and multiple updates are issued.  So yeah, I think the only solution is what I said about timestamping it.

Comment: You're most welcome, Peter.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty common to have to write more code to detect that another change has appeared, and either deny the user's edit, or attempt to merge the changes.

For example, StackOverflow does it. If you're editing a post and someone else is also editing it and saves their changes first, when you submit your edit you get an error. Then you just have to re-load the new version of the post and start over.

There may be ways to merge changes, but this is very tricky. What if the merge of two edits results in a set of properties that are mutually exclusive or otherwise makes no sense?

Another way to handle non-atomic changes (read current data, then post changes have to be handled in two separate requests in a language like PHP) is to mark the record locked while the edit is in progress. But this has other concurrency issues.

Comment: This was also my conclusion when considering options. I did consider a key-value store, but it seems more trouble than it's worth anyway.  I think that perhaps my second idea (and your suggestion here), are the best ideas, simply hold a timestamp of the last update and ensure the copy that is being submitted matches the actual last update time.  I was thinking of attempting to merge changes but I couldn't think of a good way to do this for two arrays, unless each individual property has its own "last updated" value to compare against.